# Named Pipe Blocking

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I'm currently learning named pipes and I'm trying to make a class around this notion. Here is my test main:

```
NamedPipe first("firstpipe"); // Stores the pipe name
NamedPipe second("secondpipe");
first.createPipe(); // Creates the pipe: mkfifo(mPipeName.c_str(), S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)

second.createPipe();
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    first.openPipeOut(); // my class open with O_WRONLY 
    first << "first : test of send first " << "Hello !"; // write to the file descriptor
    // My problem is here 
    std::string stringtest;
    second.openPipeIn(); // this is opening with O_RDONLY   
    second >> stringtest; // overload to read
    std::cout << stringtest << std::endl; // showing result
}
else
{
    std::string stringtest;
    first.openPipeIn(); //opening with O_RDONLY
    first >> stringtest; // overload to read
    std::cout << stringtest << std::endl; // showing result

    // my problem is here :
    second.openPipeOut(); // opening with O_WRONLY
    second << "Second test" << " Hi !"; // overload to write
}
```

The test works perfectly when I don't add this:

```
std::string stringtest;
second.openPipeIn();   //this is opening with O_RDONLY   
second >> stringtest;   // overload to read
std::cout << stringtest << std::endl; // showing result
```

and this

```
second.openPipeOut(); // opening with O_WRONLY
second << "Second test" << " Hi !"; // overload to write
```

If I do, my program is blocked and does not even show the first chain result.
Is there something I missed?

Comment: It is confusing have 'pipe in' meaning it is a pipe for writing and having 'pipe out' meaning it is a pipe for reading (and, dammit, I even screwed up while writing this comment, the first time).  That is the reverse of the normal way of thinking.

Comment: `endl` also flushes output; use it instead of the newline `\n` in the first print statements.  It will be easier for you to see what's going on.  Closing the first pipe after you've written to it in the child might also help unjam things.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will edit my first post and my code ;-) I was confused too by writing the code, i didn't knew what was in for and out for ;-) For the std::endl, it won't compile because it is not a std::string so that is why i've put "\n" ;-)

Comment: Can you post your `openPipeIn()` and `openPipeOut()` code?